# Display data on graph

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, androidplot

I am using the MpAndroidChart library to plot some data. I am using a line graph to plot the data. I want to be able to display some values at certain x indexs on top of the graph. The value I want to display is not the y values.    How can I do this?